# MomentJS not returning correct info

Tags: momentjs

I have an ISO formatted date that isn't being converted to the correct time, and I can't figure out why.

```
const m = (() => {
  console.log("Here is the original time: " + periods)
  const timeFixed = moment(periods).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss ");
  console.log("Here is the fixed time: " + timeFixed)
  return timeFixed;
})();
```

Using this, returns this:

```
Here is the original time: 2020-08-12T08:52:55Z
Here is the fixed time: Wednesday, January 1st 2020, 12:00:00
```

Any help given is appreciated as always.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Based on 2020-08-12T08:52:55Z, I would have expected Wednesday, August 12 2020, 08:52:55

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/0b7agscd/ (Also, this has nothing to do with React.)

Comment: I ran in my local with `moment`'s version of `2.27.0` and see no problem. what version of `moment` you are using?

Comment: How weird... Now I'm really confused. I put in React as that is the base for the whole project.

Comment: Save version, 2.27.0. Installed via NPM

Comment: What about node version? In this case you should provide more snippet related to this part

Comment: Node is version 12.18.1

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, weirdly. It seems Moment was having an issue with the incoming format. Converted it to a string, then it handled it.

```
const m = (() => {
    console.log("Here is the original time: " + periods)
    const timeString = new Date(periods);
    const timeFixed = moment(timeString).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss ");
    console.log("Here is the fixed time: " + timeFixed)
    return timeFixed;
    })();
```

Resulted in:

```
Here is the original time: 2020-08-12T08:52:55Z
Here is the fixed time: Wednesday, August 12th 2020, 09:52:55
```

Yes the time zone is off, but that's another problem for another day. Thanks for helping me find it.